# Symfony Vue Import Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, vue.js

I want to change my project to use Vue (currenlty using JS+jQuery / new to Vue). However I am struggeling with the `import` statement.

Currently following code worked for me perfectly:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); //load jQuery
window.locale = $('html').attr('lang'); //get the current locale specified in the html tag - returns e.g. 'en'

const lang = {
    'en': 'en_US',
    'de': 'de_DE'
};
language = (lang[locale] != null ? lang[locale] : 'en_US'); //check if specified in lang array - if not use 'en_US'

require('./select'); //another custom js file where I use the language variable
```

This code is working perfect with no issues. I can for example alert the language (en_US) in the `select.js` file and it works.

However, now I am including `Vue`. For this reason I am using the `import` statement on top of my file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'; //Vue Import
```

Now PhpStorm puts a warning on my `language` variable saying: `Unresolved variable or type language`.
I simply thought, that I forgot to declare/create the variable, so I changed the line to `let language = (lang[locale] != null ? lang[locale] : 'en_US');` which resolves the warning - but I am not able to use the variable in any other files `Uncaught ReferenceError: language is not defined`. (Vue is working btw)

Whenever I remove the `import` statement - everything works again. Any ideas??

Comment: What do you use to build your javascript ?

Comment: @Mcsky I am using [Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) which generates a single javascript file called `app.js`

Comment: Were you using webpack encore before? Or did you add it as you added Vue?

Comment: @Sergeon I used webpack before. No problems at all. After adding vue + adding any import statement it breaks (even though I don't think vue is the issue here)

Comment: Does the problem persist if you `import` any other module other than Vue?

Comment: @Sergeon yes it does